# Export User Data (GDPR requirement)

Tags: support, personal-data, gdpr

Is there a way to export all user data (questions, answers, comments, etc.) from stack exchange websites?

- If so, where can I download it?
- If not, is it a planed feature? Isn't [right of access](https://gdpr-info.eu/issues/right-of-access/) a [legal](https://gdpr-info.eu/) requirement under the current [GDPR legislation](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679)?

---

Examples of what I'm asking :

1. [Google: Download your data](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en)
2. [Facebook: Accessing & Downloading Your Information](https://www.facebook.com/help/1701730696756992?helpref=hc_global_nav)
3. [GitHub: Download all of your data](https://github.blog/2018-12-19-download-your-data/)

Comment: Does any one know if the data will also contains the deleted question/comments? or moderator notes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a data access request form at https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request. For a confirmatory staff reply, see [*Where can I download my user data? (GDPR data portability)*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312325/242059) on MSE.